# updating lastLogonTimestamp using Java code

Tags: java, active-directory

Did anyone set value of `lastLogonTimestamp` in Active Directory using a Java program?

I found following to convert `lastLogonTimestamp` to `java.util.Date` format:

https://forums.oracle.com/message/10133757#10133757

Using same logic, I am trying to modify this attribute's value:

```
    long llastLogonAdjust=11644473600000L;
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currentTimeAD = currentTime * 10000-llastLogonAdjust;
    System.out.println(currentTimeAD);
    ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
    mods[0]= new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("lastLogonTimestamp", Long.toString(currentTimeAD)));
    ldapContext.modifyAttributes(dn, mods);
```

However I am getting following error:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000209A: SvcErr: DSID-031A0DD5, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

Any idea, how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [lastLogonTimestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676824(v=vs.85).aspx), only the system can update this value.  You cannot set this value using Java or anything else.

Edit:

Look at this [blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx) ([Internet Archive backup](http://web.archive.org/web/20130517114056/http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/04/15/the-lastlogontimestamp-attribute-what-it-was-designed-for-and-how-it-works.aspx)) by Warren Williams for explanation about the lastLogonTimestamp attribute:

> It is important to note that the intended purpose of the lastLogontimeStamp attribute to help identify inactive computer and user accounts. The lastLogon attribute is not designed to provide real time logon information. With default settings in place the lastLogontimeStamp will be 9-14 days behind the current date.
>
> If you are looking for more “real-time” logon tracking you will need to query the Security Event log on your DC’s for the desired logon events i.e. 528 –Windows XP\2003 and earlier or 4624 Windows Vista\2008 . See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx) ([InternetArchive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130602110914/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx)) by Eric Fitzgerald for more info. (I think he knows something about auditing)
>
> IMO your best bet for near real-time data is to use an event log collection service to gather all domain controller security event logs to a centralized database. You can then query a single database for the desired logon events. Microsoft’s solution for security event log collection is [Audit Collection Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb381373.aspx). There are many 3rd party solutions as well.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will you know why it's not getting updated when user logs in (using AD in WebLogic authentication provider)? Ideally it should get updated, isn't it? How are we supposed to store last logon time in AD then? Using some custom attribute or unused attribute? Thanks.

Comment: @ankur Please see edit.  Custom attribute or unused attribute is always a possibility, but that assumes that they only login through your code.

Comment: Thanks very much for help. I think I'll use some unused attribute, probably 'comment' attribute. I understood all that conceptually but getting this last logon information from 'audit log' through Java seems complex task and anyway these users are going to use only my application for login.